# Grouping already clustered data (with a pre-defined x and y)

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, tsne

I have an already clustered data set (I wanna keep my x and y), where there's clearly a small group of elements in the middle that don't follow the expected patterns.

I can select them manually, but I wonder if there's a way of automating the selection part of these elements, efficiently.

Something like using just the grouping part of a clustering algorithm, I've been trying it with a threshold, but it doesn't produce good results in cases that won't form a circular cluster.

[image: Already clustered data]

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know which clustering technique are you using.

You can use

- **Partition-based Clustering**: for example K-Means Clustering, not that good with outliers.
- **Hierarchical-based Clustering**: Produces trees of clusters (Agglomerative, Divisive). You get a Dendogram.
- **Density-based Clustering**: produces arbitrary shaped clusters, for example DBSCAN

If you are looking something other that a circular cluster and you need clusters within clusters, I would try DBSCAN. It locates regions of high density and separate outliers and it can find clusters within clusters.

If you are using Python you can use DBSCAN with sklearn

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Can I keep my x and y with those algorithms?

Comment: If you use DBSCAN you would have to redo the analysis. Unless you apply the analysis to the clusters as x and y (not sure if you can do that).

Comment: But that is what I wanted, to keep the x and y that I have and try to group it. Because I need to use this algorithm I made.

Comment: You could apply DBSCAN to the subgroups of data, piping in the X/Y output from whatever prior analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You have it right, that you want your clustering to tell you which points are most anomalous. For k-means clustering it's the points that are farthest from their assigned cluster.

I don't see a reason to expect that the anomalies form a cluster themselves. If that's what you're expecting you may need to compute something else, like, a clustering of the points beyond a threshold?

Also consider a Gaussian mixture clustering, which is just like k-means except treats cluster assignments as soft and probabilistic. The outliers under that model might make more sense.

Comment: I get your point, but I don't want to calculate the clustering process again, I've tried using k-means and didn't get very good results.
I just want something that I can apply after my clustering algorithm runs that can separate groups without changing x or y and doesn't need human suport.

Comment: Sure, why not cluster only the outliers? you're looking for a cluster of them, it seems.

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to find the outliers automatically and not manually, something like you said "a clustering of the points beyond a threshold".

Comment: I just can't find a way of defining this threshold.